# How can I restore an item from the Trash in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, trash

Windows provides restore item to the position from where it was deleted.

But I couldn't find any option to restore an item from trash.

Is it possible to restore an item from where it was moved to trashed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This feature is in Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/enhancements-refinements.html), which is being released this Friday. It's not present in current versions of Mac OS X.

Comment: Wow. Damn. Mac OS 7 (well, "System 7" at the time) could do this. WTF.

Comment: yes, it's one of the things they missed from OS X 10.0 and have only just got around to reintroducing.

Comment: Before Snow Leopard:
- click on the trash
- move the deleted item to where you want

Answer (score 2):

If you recently trashed it, you can undo the move under Edit, Undo.  Not nearly as useful if you keep your trash full.

Answer (score 1):

As SidneySM [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/30287/how-can-i-restore-an-item-from-the-trash-in-mac-os-x/30291#30291), this feature has just been added to Snow Leopard.

On all other versions, you will just have to drag-and-drop the file out of the trash and back to where you want it. The trash will not remember where the original location of the file.