# How to Recover XCode project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have put my all xcodeproject in the desktop folder but accidently deleted the entire contents of the desktop!

Can anyone tell me how to recover the source code of .xcodeproj?

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a programming question.

You're really asking: "How do I undelete a file on a Mac?"

That is a question which is better suited to SuperUser.com.  If you look there you will find: [How can I restore an item from the Trash in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/30287/how-can-i-restore-an-item-from-the-trash-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have all your code, and are just missing the project file - create a new empty project with the same name, and drag all your old code back into it.